# JQuery UI's Droppable's greedy option not working when extending with widget factory

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When I extend the jQuery UI droppable widget with the widget factory, the greedy option isn't working anymore.
See following [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/yekepuceru/1/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1):

I investigated this issue and the problem is the following:

When a widget is created on an element the widget instance is saved as a data attribute to the element, to retrieve the instance if necessary. The key used to save the instance is the widgets 'widgetFullName' property, which is the namespace and the name of the widget, eg. for the droppable that is 'ui-droppable'. If I extend the widget and set a new namespace and name for the widget, a created instance will saved to the element with the new namespace-name key.

So far so good.

The problem is that in the logic of droppable(and other related widgets like draggable, sortable and the ddmanager) droppables are searched with the following selector:

```
":data(ui-droppable)"
```

'ui-droppable'is hard coded and so it won't find any instances which where created by the extended droppable, because the key is different.

I tried to fix that by replacing all hard coded 'ui-droppable' keys by this.widgetFullName. That works fine inside the code of ui.droppable but outside from that, this does not refer to the droppable anymore and so widgetFullName isn't the correct key. To fix this more investigation and change of logic is required.

There is still a 'dirty' way to fix this, but this comes with one downside:

Instead of extending the widget, I redefined it:

```
$.widget('ui.droppable', ui.droppable, {
  extension of the widget
};
```

The namespace does not change and it works as expected, the downside being, that you redefined the widget and you can't create different droppables.

Comment: I created a bug ticket bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/11578. Unfortunately the jquery ui team won't fix it, because nobody could supply a plausible implementation.